# how to check the div value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to set the div CSS styles using javascript? I have a problem with getting the value of class name. 
Please help if anyone know it.

```
<div class="this_is_i_want_to_set_the_background_color" id="divname"></div>
<div class="test" id="divname"></div>

var className = $('.divname').attr('class');
var t = 'divalue';
if(className == t){
    $('.divname').css('background', '#0962ae');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `.hasClass` method:

```
$('.divname').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('divalue')) {
        $(this).css('background', '#0962ae');
    }
});
```

But there is one simpler way to do this:

```
// an element with class 'divname' also has class 'divalue'
$('.divname.divalue').css('background', '#0962ae');
```

Comment: Good thing you've edited your answer. Didn't get why people were upvoting you as your first answer was clearly faulted.

Comment: @Kippie The first answer showed that `hasClass` is the right way to check if an element has a certain class what the op wants to do. While, the second one is better.

Comment: true, but before you edited your answer looked like gregorkas' answer a bit further down, without the usage of ``this`` or ``each``

Comment: @xerwudjohn Where is `divname`?

Comment: i want to set the **class** of the specific div in css using javascript :(

Comment: @xdazz you answer is correct but there is an fault there the divname should be in "#divname". hehe. but thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

it can be shorten as

```
var t = 'divalue';
$('.divname.' + t).css('background', '#0962ae');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you already select only '.divname' ? It will never work because it becomes like this:

```
if('divname'=='divvalue')
```

Instead, you can write what you want to achieve and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the jQuery hasClass function (doc: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/),
for example:

```
if($('.divname').hasClass('divalue')){
    $('.divname').css('background', '#0962ae');
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but I think the point of the question was how to check the class, not the code itself. If the code would actually have to be correct, it would be unnecessary to check for the class anyway, because you could just use $('.divname.divalue').css('background', '#0962ae');